# How to access HTTP headers from a given url?

Tags: perl, http-headers, lwp

I am looking for a way to get `http headers` from a given url. I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use warnings;
#use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get("http://cpan.org");
print $res->header('Content-Length');
```

The above code prints nothing. So, where am I going wrong here or is there any better way to access headers.

Comment: Your script returned 8019 for me...

Comment: @Kenosis: /facepalm was not connected to the internet while using this script. Anyways how can one extract the user-agent field. I tried `$res->header('agent')` but it didn't worked or I have to explicitly set `User-Agent` and than retrieve it.

Comment: There's no such thing as a Agent header in an HTTP response.

Comment: In case the following may be helpful: [How to set User-Agent with LWP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232504/how-to-set-user-agent-with-lwp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get("http://cpan.org");
print $res->headers->as_string;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the result of the request before you assume that you can use it as if it worked:

```
use v5.10;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get("http://444.cpan.org");

if( $res->is_success ) {
    say "Content length is ", $res->header('Content-Length');
    }
else {
    say "Error! ", $res->code;
    }
```

Remember that a Content-Length header does not mean that you had a successful request. An error response might still contain a message body, which would have a length.